# Anonymous clickhandler in foreach loop uses last variable state

Tags: forms, powershell

I guess this is a newbie question. Yet I did not find anything online...

I'm creating a small powershell script with a very simple gui.

This is the relevant part of the script:

```
foreach ($script in $scripts){
  $btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button  
  #Text, Location, Size omitted

  #Add clickhandler
  $btn.Add_Click(
    {    
      Write-Host "Clicked on Btn $script"
      Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -ArgumentList "-command", "`"$script`""
      Write-Host "finished"
      $Form.Close();
    }
  )
  $Form.Controls.Add($btn)
}
```

Obviously `$scripts` contains paths pointing towards other powershell scripts. 
Being a Java developer I was naiv enough to suspect every click handler to be created with its own reference to a script location (`$script`).

But of course powershell does not evaluate `$script` until the handler is invoked. Thus, every button will call the last element in my array `$scripts` since `$script` will reference the last element in `$scripts` after the loop completes.

How can I create a click handler inside a `foreach`-loop based on the loop-variable itself?

## Solution

Mathias R. Jessen pointed me to a working solution. `.GetNewClosure()` called on the handler worked.

Working Code:

```
foreach ($script in $scripts){
  $btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button  
  #Text, Location, Size omitted

  #Add clickhandler
  $btn.Add_Click(
    {    
      Write-Host "Clicked on Btn $script"
      Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -ArgumentList "-command", "`"$script`""
      Write-Host "finished"
      $Form.Close();
    }.GetNewClosure()
  )
  $Form.Controls.Add($btn)
}
```

Comment: `$using:script`

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I get an error saying `$using:var` does neither work with `Write-Host` nor `Start-Process`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329856/powershell-button-handler-and-passing-parameters - from what I can see this answers your question.

Comment: AddClick({...}.GetNewClosure())

Comment: .GetNewClosure() did the trick. Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Mathias R. Jessen pointed me to a working solution. .GetNewClosure() called on the handler worked.

Working Code:

```
foreach ($script in $scripts){
  $btn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button  
  #Text, Location, Size omitted

  #Add clickhandler
  $btn.Add_Click(
    {    
      Write-Host "Clicked on Btn $script"
      Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -ArgumentList "-command", "`"$script`""
      Write-Host "finished"
      $Form.Close();
    }.GetNewClosure()
  )
  $Form.Controls.Add($btn)
}
```